# Displaying bootstrap 3 tab when validation fails

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a single form across multiple bootstrap 3 tabs. When i click on submit button, i validate all input fields across tabs using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""    
});
```

And i show the tabs with error with the following function

```
function LoadTabWithError() {    
    $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
        var id = $(tab).attr("id");
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
    });    
}

$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {        
    LoadTabWithError();
}
```

Everything works fine except for one scenario. When i click on submit button, say the error is on tab2, it does not show tab2. It just validates and displays error in tab2. When i click on submit again for the second time, then it goes to tab 2.

I think the function LoadTabWithError(); is called before form is validated. In which event should i call the function  so that it displays the correct tab from the first time itself.

Comment: put the click function in `document.ready` and use `on-click` . May be that help .

Comment: Are your tabs being generated dynamically ?

Comment: For a proper solution, we'd need to see the relevant HTML markup.  What does the markup for the button look like?  Where is your call to `.validate()`?

Comment: No @Tushar Raj. They are static tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `click()` handler interferes with how the jQuery Validate plugin normally operates.  This is why the developer has provided various callback functions that fire based on certain events.

If you want to do something special when the submit button is clicked AND the form is still invalid, like showing a tab, then you would use [the `invalidHandler` callback option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) in the `.validate()` method.

Get rid of any external click handlers, get rid of your `LoadTabWithError` function, and properly leverage [the available options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) within `.validate()`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#yourForm').validate({ // <- initialize the plugin on this form
        ignore: [],  // <- proper format to set ignore to "nothing"
        invalidHandler:  function(event, validator) {
            $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
            });
        },
        // ... the rest of your validate() options
    });

});
```

These options could also be placed within `.setDefaults()`, however, in this case, when you only have one form on the page, `.setDefaults()` is totally pointless.  In any case, you would still need to call the `.validate()` method to initialize the plugin on your form, unless your ASP framework is already handling this initialization for you; then you have no choice...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: [],  // <- proper format to set ignore to "nothing"
    invalidHandler:  function(event, validator) {
        $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
            var id = $(tab).attr("id");
            $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
        });
    },
    // ... the rest of your options
});
```

Comment: $('#yourform').validate ({ ignore:[] }) is not working for me. Whereas if i set the same in $.Validator.setDefaults({ ignore:[] }) is working. Any idea?

Comment: In my case, whatever i set in the validate is not working. even the rules. Whereas if i set the rules individually, they do work.    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='SelectedForumList']").rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Forum is Required."
        }
    });

Comment: @vanitha,  Yes, please re-read the part where I mention your ASP framework and say, _"unless your ASP framework is already handling this initialization for you"_.  It's because your frame is handling the `.validate()` part (initialization) so you're only left with being able to use `.setDefaults()` and `.rules()`.

Comment: ok. but the invalidHandler is not getting fired when there is an error. I have set this in $.validator.setDefaults({})

Comment: @vanitha, as already explained, it does not fire on a single error... `invalidHandler` fires when you click to submit when the form is still invalid.  Otherwise, if you cannot figure this out, create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue so we have something to look at.

Comment: @Sparky is it not better to put this code in the highlight property rather then the invalidHandler?

Comment: @Wilky, the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks will fire every time any part of the form is valid or invalid, as per any triggering event.   As stated in my answer, the `invalidHandler` callback will only fire when *attempting to submit an invalid form*.  The OP clearly stated that he is expecting this to happen when the submit button is clicked and the form is invalid.